# How to load a script on a specific template in laravel?

Tags: php

I need load script in specific template blade file.
Is it right to write something like that:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="app"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src='somescript.js'> </script> //here script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specific Blade View File**

```
@section('pageSpecificJs')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/jquery.validate.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
 });
</script>
@stop
```

**Bottom of Footer file**

```
 @yield('pageSpecificJs')
</body>
</html>
```